# Alternating Wordpress Posts

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, posts

I am using the JointsWP for a Wordpress site that I am creating for a client.

They want the posts to alternate when the posts are looping.

For example, POST1: feature image on the left and title/excerpt on the right; POST2: title/excerpt on the left, feature image on the right. Etc etc.

Has anyone found any luck with this?

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'offset' => 2, );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="large-6 columns">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
</div>
<div class="large-6 columns">
<?php the_date(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
</a>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
<hr>
</div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: Is `$myposts` an associative array or an indexed array?

Comment: It's set up as an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind people, I found that Zurb has a functionality to accomplish this goal with a simple class.

Just going to create a counter to count the posts and make it a different class.

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/grid.html#source-ordering